# How to override only 1 Http Method (POST) in a @RestController, but let Spring handle all the other Http methods with a standard HATEOAS response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-hateoas

I want to expose some REST resources in Spring, by default I can just let Spring Boot deal with this and this generates a nice HATEOAS response where I get everything 'free'.

Now I need to perform some logic when a certain resource is being POSTED, so I implemented my own @RestController class and override the POST method as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;

import java.net.URI;
import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(Constants.PROJECTSPATH)
public class ProjectController {
    @Autowired private ProjectRepository projectRepo;
    @Autowired private ProjectRoleRepository projectRoleRepo;
    @Autowired private AccountRepository accountRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProject(@RequestBody Project projectFromRequest, Principal principal) {
        Project project = projectRepo.save(projectFromRequest);
        Account currentAccount = accountRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        ProjectRole ownerRole = new ProjectRole(project, currentAccount, ProjectRoleEnum.OWNER);
        projectRoleRepo.save(ownerRole);

        final URI uri =
                MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromController(getClass())
                        .path("/{id}")
                        .buildAndExpand(project.getId())
                        .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new ProjectResource(project));
    }
}
```

I use a class inheriting from ResourceSupport and in there I generate the required links for a HATEOAS response. So far so good, that isn't too much custom work.

The problem is that if I now just try to GET all projects, I get this message:

> {"timestamp":1518610270403,"status":405,"error":"Method Not
>   Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request
>   method 'GET' not supported","path":"/projects"}

I really prefer not to implement the other methods too, the default done by Spring Boot is great. But am I now forced to implement these as well and keep my entire HATEOAS response up to date with my domain object changes every time? That is functionality that I love 'out of the box'.

Comment: In your @RequestMapping annotation you specify POST as the method that Spring should map to your `/projects` endpoint. But you havent specified a GET endpoint, and thus you get the message above. What exactly were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @BThuy: I was hoping that everything would still work as if I didn't add a RestController class for this resource at all. If I don't, then Spring Boot injects some kind of handler and generates correct HATEOAS responses, as it still does for my other resources.

Comment: Can you update your post and show your whole controller class?

Comment: @BThuy Sure but there isn't much more to see.

Perhaps you don't know about this default functionality if running a Spring Boot application, for example check out https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/. It's very easy to expose resources without having any controller at all.

Comment: It's been updated.

Comment: Indeed, I was not aware of this default behaviour. Thanks! But what I can tell you for sure is that by default an endpoint supports all standard HTTP operations (e.g. GET, POST, PUT, ...). When you link an endpoint to a particular operation (in your case POST), then you effectively limit that endpoint to that particular operation (hence the message you get when trying to use GET). I am afraid it looks like you will have to define the other operations for that endpoint manually. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to override only 1 Http Method (POST) in a @RestController, but let Spring handle all the other Http methods with a standard HATEOAS response

You can't do that with a `@RestController`. As stated in the [Spring Data REST reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers):

> Sometimes you may want to write a custom handler for a specific resource. To take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling, and more, use the `@RepositoryRestController` annotation instead of a standard Spring MVC @Controller or @RestController

It is not explicitly mentionned, but annotating your controller with `@RepositoryRestController` allows you to define a custom behavior for one endpoint while keeping all the other endpoints that Spring automatically generates.

For older versions, note that you can use the `@RequestMapping` annotation at the [method level only](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535). Issue fixed in  2.4 M1 (Gosling), 2.3.1 (Fowler SR1), 2.1.6 (Dijkstra SR6).

Your example becomes:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(/project)
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired private ProjectRepository projectRepo;
    @Autowired private ProjectRoleRepository projectRoleRepo;
    @Autowired private AccountRepository accountRepo;

    @PostMapping(Constants.PROJECTSPATH) // @PostMapping is a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST). path can be something like "/prj" (beginning with slash, because on class level, there is no suffix slash)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProject(@RequestBody Project projectFromRequest, Principal principal) {
        Project project = projectRepo.save(projectFromRequest);
        Account currentAccount = accountRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        ProjectRole ownerRole = new ProjectRole(project, currentAccount, ProjectRoleEnum.OWNER);
        projectRoleRepo.save(ownerRole);

        final URI uri =
                MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromController(getClass())
                        .path("/{id}")
                        .buildAndExpand(project.getId())
                        .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new ProjectResource(project));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for but wasn't sure if existed, thanks!

Comment: I just found that a major downside to this is that the MvcUriComponentBuilder.fromController doesn't return the path anymore, which makes sense since it doesn't know about it anymore. I replaced it with this:

        `Method currentMethod = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();

        final URI uri =MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethod(getClass(), currentMethod, projectFromRequest, principal)`

Not pretty in particular though.